# Can someone write a good Q/A on port-forwarding?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

I think we need a question where we have gathered (router-agnostic) good advice on how to set up port-forwarding on a home network.

Then we could close questions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/283907/how-to-use-a-different-private-port-to-a-public-port) and point it to our port-forwarding-faq.

Afterwards when we have some good info someone brave can convert it to a SU blog entry.

Comment: More power to you @Nifle. Just do it and add the community-faq-proposed tag.;-)

Comment: Agreed on that. Problem is that many people don't know they actually *want* port forwarding.

Comment: After you get it going you should blog about it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added this question to get us started:

## [What is Port Forwarding and what is it used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)

> There are a lot of questions on 'port forwarding' but there doesn't seem to be one that cleary states what it is and what it's used for. So:
>
> 1. What is Port Forwarding?
> 2. What is it used for, and why would I need it?

I think that we still need an overview of how to set one up as well.  (also if it hasn't been done, will a mod please make it CW)

Answer (score 1):

@KronoS asks a double barreled question that could cause answers to split in different directions. Isn't it better to simple ask separate questions?

**1) What is Port Forwarding?**
(I think the answers to this question will by definition include all relevant information).

**2) How do I set up Port Forwarding (on a home network)?**
(Based on the original post above)

I'm not sure why you want to restrict the question to only home networks. Perhaps it's better to just say:
**2) How do I use Port Forwarding to allow external computers to access my internal network**

Just a thought.